# Allure Framework: using @Step and @Attachment annotations with TestNG and Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, allure

I am working on a project that uses [Allure framework](https://github.com/allure-framework/) with Java, TestNG and Maven.
But I'm unable to generate correct XML files while using Allure @Step and @Attachment annotations in my Java program. Any sample code demonstrating usage of the above annotations is appreciated.
I am using Allure 1.4.0.RC8.

Comment: XML files don't use annotations.

Comment: Probably incorrectly edited question. Fixed now.

Comment: @JavaCreeper: do you consider my answer correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These annotations are used in the same way with any Java-based test framework.

**To create a step:**

- Create method with any visibility modifier (public, private, protected) with step logic and annotate it with @Step annotation. You can optionally specify step name in annotation attributes.
- Call this method inside test method.

An example:

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    //Some code...
    stepLogic();
    //Some more assertions...
}

@Step("This is step 1")
private void step1Logic() {
    // Step1 implementation
} 

@Step("This is step 2")
private void step2Logic() {
    // Step2 implementation
}
```

To create an attachment:

- Create method with any visibility which return **byte[]** - attachment contents and annotate it with **@Attachment** annotation.
- Call this method inside any test

Example:

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    //Some code...
    createAttachment();
    //Some more assertions...
}

@Attachment(name = "My cool attachment")
private byte[] createAttachment() {
    String content = "attachmentContent";
    return content.getBytes();
}
```

In order to make **@Step** and **@Attachment** annotations work you need to correctly enable AspectJ in your configuration. This is usually done via **-javaagent** JVM argument pointing to **aspectj-weaver.jar** file.

Further reading:

- [Using with TestNG](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG)
- [Steps](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Steps)
- [Attachments](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Attachments)

Comment: do you have any suggestions how i would add aspectj-weaver.jar as javaagent if i'm invoking testng test suite inside spring-boot application. (not as tests for those application but at runtime to rerun some end2end tests when user so pleases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parameters for the `@Step` annotation. For example, if the method accepts some variables:

```
@Step("Get the maximum between {a} and {b}")
public int max(int a, int b){
    //implementation
}
```

If you need to use any object, you can override `toString()` method, or use needed parameters:

```
public class User {

     private String name;
     private String password;
     ...
}

@Step("Type {user.name} / {user.password}.")
public void loginWith(User user) {
     ...
}
```