# Isn't it possible to print the Reporter.log messages in Allure report?

Tags: testng, reporting, allure

I have recently integrated Allure reporting into my existing TestNG framework and it works fine. However I could not see any of the Reporter.log messages in the Allure report. Isn't this supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allure supports a lot of test frameworks for multiple languages and because of that it doesn't know about Reporter.log. However you can attach this file to any selected case as usually using **@Attachment** annotation. Take a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163853/allure-framework-using-step-and-attachment-annotations-with-testng-and-maven) for more details about attachments.

Comment: I am able to implement it, thanks! But, when I am using it, it appears as link. I need to click on that link and then it shows me the text. It shows the method name as link. But I want logs to display straight away not method name as link to logs.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a different way to log Reporter.log messages to the Allure report, for those interested simply in adding logs to the report besides saving the log file itself as an attachment.

I created an Allure step, like this:

```
@Step("{0}") 
public void logToReport(String message) {
    log(message); //or System.out.println(message);
}
```

@Step({0}) will then add the message to the Allure report.